# Strange KVO keyPath naming convention when observing a property with the same name as its type?

Tags: objective-c, key-value-observing

I just stumbled over a weird behaviour in Obj-C when observing a property which name "matches" its type in lowercase

Example: if the property is called `foo` and its type is `Foo` then the keyPath to observe is *not* `@"foo"` but `@"Foo"` which does not seem right. Or does it?

Note that I used the "out of the box" KVO with getters/setters and KVO event emitting handled automatically.

**Example code**

Foo.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Foo : NSObject
@end
```

Foo.m

```
#import "Foo.h"

@implementation Foo
@end
```

KVOTest.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Foo.h"

@interface KVOTest : NSObject

@property Foo *foo;

-(void)test;

@end
```

KVOTest.m

```
#import "KVOTest.h"
#import "Foo.h"

@implementation KVOTest

-(void)test {

    // this won't work
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"foo" options:0 context:nil];
    // this does work
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"Foo" options:0 context:nil];

    self.foo = [[Foo alloc] init];

    [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"foo"];
    [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"Foo"];
}

-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSKeyValueChangeKey,id> *)change context:(void *)context {
    NSLog(@"keypath: %@", keyPath);
}

@end
```

main.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "KVOTest.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        KVOTest *kvo = [KVOTest new];
        [kvo test];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I checked Apples KVO documentation but did not find this case covered.

Also I did not find any references to this on SO so I wonder if this is a bug or a feature due to the potential "clash" between type and propery name?

Comment: Please provide relevant code.

Comment: Weird, but if you don't observe `Foo`, `foo` does work. Maybe it's because `Foo` and `foo` both claim setter `setFoo:`. The class has nothing to do with it, I see the same behaviour when the property is `MyTestProperty` or `myTestProperty` and/or the class is `NSString`.